# return back data of related the foreign key before submitting the form django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

im trying to return back some data based on selected item , i have an application which everyone can order mobile cases sometimes happen the user wants to order 4 mobile cases but in our storage only has 3  i have to do something before submitting the form it will display the quantities of the selected item !
if quantity in `Item` table = 3 but i have write 4 in the `ItemsInvoice` i want to show an alert if write more than 3 ? is it possible please ?

```
class Item(models.Model):
     items = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     quantity = models.IntegerField()
     def __str__(self):
        return self.items 

class Invoice(models.Model):
     seller = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     items = models.ManyToManyField(Item,through='ItemsInvoice')

class ItemsInvoice(models.Model):
     invoice= models.ForeignKey(Invoice,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     quantity = models.IntegerField()
     price = models.IntegerField()
```

i have prevent submitting the form if we dont have enough items , but i want to display it before trying to submit the form

```html
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{items.management_form}}
        <div class="p-1 pr-2 pb-1 text-xs border border-black rounded-lg flex flex-wrap" style="direction: rtl;">
           
            <div class="flex w-8/12 lg:w-9/12">
                
                <div class="">
                      customer name  :
                  </div>        

                <div class="w-10/12 ml-8 border-b border-gray-600 border-dotted">
                    {{form.customer | add_class:'bg-transparent w-full text-center focus:outline-none customer' }}
                    {% if form.customer.errors %}
                    <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{form.customer.errors}}</div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- table -->
        <div class="mt-1 border border-black" style="direction: rtl;">
            <!-- header -->
            <div class="flex flex-wrap grayBG text-sm text-white">
                <div class="w-3/12  border-r text-center">
                    item
                </div> 
                <div class="w-1/12  border-r text-center">
                    quantity
                </div>  
                <div class="w-1/12  border-r text-center">
                    price
                </div>            
            </div>
            <!-- inputs -->
            <div id="allInp" class="text-right">
                {% for item in items.forms %}

                {{item.id}}
                <div class="flex flex-wrap grayBG text-sm text-black inp">
                    <div class="w-20 md:w-3/12 p-2 border-r text-center">
                        {{item.item | add_class:'w-full item rounded-lg text-center focus:outline-none py-1' }}                    
                        {% if item.item.errors %}
                        <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{item.item.errors}}</div>
                        {% endif %}
    
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-16 md:w-1/12 p-2 border-r text-center ">
                        {{item.quantity | add_class:'rounded-lg dana text-center focus:outline-none py-1 w-full'}}                    
                        {% if item.quantity.errors %}
                        <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{item.quantity.errors}}</div>
                        {% endif %}

                    </div> 
                    <div class="w-16 md:w-1/12 p-2 border-r text-center ">
                        {{item.price | add_class:'rounded-lg nrx text-center focus:outline-none py-1 w-full' }}                    
                        {% if item.price.errors %}
                        <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{item.price.errors}}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>                                   
                
                </div>                
                {% endfor %}

            </div>          
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="w-6/12 text-center mt-1 mx-auto mb-6">
        <button type="submit" class="w-full bg-white text-gray-900">print</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

for example i select mobile phone case the i will fill out the quantity to 4 but in our storage it only remains 3 , i have defined the quantities in the Item

Comment: HI, there are mutliple quantity inputs ? can you show output of this html structure ? Also , you need to show alert onsubmit ?

Comment: i posted it all

Comment: did you tried using ajax here ?

Comment: no , im not good at ajax , i know i should use ajax but i dont know how to do it

Comment: show html generated code so that i can create demo code for you .

Comment: but i posted all of the templates